# How to update array element in firestore with golang?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

Following code:

```
Lobby := map[string]interface{}{
        "table_id"          :"new table id",
        "Status"            : true,
        "name"              : "shivam",
        "array":[]interface{}{0,1,3},// this replace existing array with new values
    }

result, err := client.Collection("lobbies").Doc("12").Set(ctx,Lobby,firestore.MergeAll)
```

I just want to update 2nd element in array with the new value

Comment: FYI: your current code is replacing document, not updating it. To update some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document, use the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) method.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs thanx for the reply. As per google doc, I am using mergeall method for update above mention fields. there are many more fields exist in document that dont want to update so its not mention here.https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: If I understood you correctly, this has nothing to do with Firestore and databases in general, your question is *How to replace 2nd element in a slice*?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs. No, In firestore databse I have document, That have field called "array" (as array type) that have 3 values right now 0,2,3,4,5,6 , I want replace first 3 values i.e 0,2,3 with 0,1,3. But when i am doing like this it will repace all values in array.

Comment: Of course it will be overwritten. `array` fields stores a slice and is not a map, so you need to implement your own code that will regenerate that slice in the way you need and replace it in document.

Comment: Okay, So there is no other way to do it. Thanx BTW :) @AndrejsCainikovs

Comment: I posted an answer, and I hope you'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to inform a database to replace a specific element in a slice or array.

Your `array` field stores a slice and is not a map, so you need to implement your own code that will regenerate that slice in the way you need and replace it in the document, something like:

```
Lobby := map[string]interface{} {
    "table_id" : "new table id",
    "Status"   : true,
    "name"     : "shivam",
    "array"    : []interface{}{0,1,3},
}

new_slice, err := change_my_slice(Lobby["array"])
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("Error message goes here")
    return nil, err
}
Lobby["array"] = new_slice

result, err := client.Collection("lobbies").Doc("12").Set(ctx,Lobby,firestore.MergeAll)
```

Comment: There is a way now, it's just not supported in Go: arrayUnion(). Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently possible, although advertised as "Not yet supported" at [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Here's a slightly modified example.

```golang
type User struct {
    Address      string     `firestore:"address"`
    Hobbies      []Stickers `firestore:"hobbies"`
}
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
    "context"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, "project-id")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Client Error", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    co := client.Doc("User/Frank")
    _, err := co.Update(ctx, []firestore.Update{
        {Path: "hobbies", Value: firestore.ArrayUnion("Simping")},
    })
    if err != nil {
       log.Println("Update error", err)
    }
    
}
```

You can check the documentation of `ArrayUnion` and `ArrayRemove` at [pkg](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore@v1.6.1#ArrayUnion)